# C# - VS Code - launch:program ... does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am trying to debug a simple "Hello world" application in VS Code, however, when I press Ctrl + F5, it gives me the following error:

[image]

If I manually change the path in launch.json from:

```
${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/insert-target-framework-here/insert-project-name-here.dll
```

To:

```
"${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/test.dll"
```

It does work, however before it was working fine without me manually typing the path. Also, I have noticed that VS Code no longer asks to rebuild assets like it did before:

[image]

So far I have tried the following:

Uninstalled VS Code, then .NET Core 2.1, deleted the VS Code extension folder from %USER%\.vscode\ , re-installed VS Code, then .NET Core 2.1, and then the C# extension (C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)).

When the VS Code starts, it does download the "OmniSharp" package successfully, but still, no prompt to rebuild assets when I open a C# file. Debugging gives the same issue as before.

Here is the launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
```

And the tasks.json:

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "command": "dotnet build",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.
My VS Code was giving me the same error message, and what I did to fix it was:

```
- Press the combination Ctrl + Shift + P
- Restart Omnisharp
- Then it asks if you want to add missing files for build.
- Click Yes.
```

After this I was able to debug my app.

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

Visit your **\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1** in your project folder (That you open in VS)

Go to launch.json file in VS:

**Replace**:
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug//.dll",

**With**:
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/`CSharp`.dll",

In may case, the project is called `CSharp`. Watch out.

Answer (score 2):

I had a the same error. The debugger was looking for the .dll file in `${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/myApp.dll` but the file was located in `${workspaceFolder}/bin/MCD/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/tradeAppl.dll`

After changing the launch.json file to read

```
...
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/MCD/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/tradeAppl.dll",
...
```

I was able to debug the application without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have :".dll" taged with "<" and ">", it means that you have give it a value.
The easiest way to do it is to open the project in VSCode and use find&replace to replace the:

with your project name which I do believe its: "test" as per the .dll name

Comment: As mentioned in my post:

If I manually change the path in launch.json from "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll" to "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/test.dll", it does work, however, it was working fine before without replacing anything in the launch.json

Comment: usually, this happens in case of VSCode stopped responding during the project creation only.

Comment: VS Code does not stop responding at any point. Also, I have tried creating new application more than few times, still the same.

Comment: @GiedriusElectrum I had this happen when upgrading to a newer version of .netcore. Your app will compile to a different directory in the bin folder and you'll need to point to that new directory in the launch.json.

Comment: Experienced a similar problem in ubuntu. Launched vs code with the following command, code - - no-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I switched to MS Visual Studio, since I did not find any other solutions.

Comment: Experienced a similar problem in ubuntu. Launched vs code with the following command, code - - no-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Configure your Launch.json like this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/parsalotfy/10a466c0681fc14bdd86debee7e9789d)

And there is no need to Tasks.json , you can Press F5 to build or configure it your self to which command should be run in default shell when you press F5

Answer (score 0):

```
// "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll",
   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/csharp_multi_threads.dll",
```

You need to change the program value as it reminded

Answer (score 0):

-Right Click on Project Name And Click on Reveal in Explorer
-Copy Url In Explorer After Folder Name
For Example My Folder Address is
D:\IOT\Projects\LWSIOT_WebApiWM2\LWSIOT_WebApiWM2\LWSIOT_WebApiWM2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\LWSIOT_WebApiWM2.dll
And In Launch.json :
${workspaceFolder}/LWSIOT_WebApiWM2/LWSIOT_WebApiWM2/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/LWSIOT_WebApiWM2.dll
-Paste in Launch.json on "Program":"<Your_Address>"
-Click On Debug And Its OK

Answer (score 0):

In launch.json , replace :

"program": "${workspaceFolder}/Api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Api.dll",

with:

"program": "${workspaceFolder}/Api/bin/linux/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Api.dll"

Since I was running code in Linux machine so I should have provided Linux Folder' path

Answer (score 0):

Must be an issue with the path to the dll in the `program` property of the `launch.json` file.

In my case, it still contained the old .net core framework version after the version upgrade.