# Visual Studio Code DotNet Core Project "ProjectName.dll" does not exist

Tags: asp.net-core, vscode-debugger, worker-service

I received new project file. Its actually `.NET Core Worker Service` Project. Created using VS Code. I tried to Manually build the service. but in there no have any `dll` file. because I only changed the project name after its received. Now I tried to run my project. but I got error. its says

```
launch: program 'C:My Folders\Glm'
Projects\DBDataService\bin\Debug\netcoreapp5.0\win7-x64\'DBDataService.dll' does not exist
```

Can you please tell me how to setup my local environment with dll file in VS Code. I am new to VS code actually. How to manually setup dll file in project

Answer (score 0):

VSCode was looking for the DBDataService.dll program, but could not find it.

You only need to configure your environment and then correctly define everything (especially "programs") in your launch.json.

Try to change,

"program": "${file}"

${file} is a predefined variable in VS Code for the current opened file. Refer to：

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

You can also refer to this post, which may help you:

[C# - VS Code - launch:program ... does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391861/c-sharp-vs-code-launchprogram-does-not-exist)

Create a debugging file：

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: in my case i did not create this project. I got source code only. there is no have any Debug file. so how to create a new debug file with dll file. i have already changed my "program" file. but i need to create debug file now. also with the dll file

Comment: Create a debugging file refer to this article:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging